# Zend Framework integration with Behat BDD

Tags: php, zend-framework, tdd, bdd, behat

Anyone has been using [Behat](http://behat.org/) with Zend Framework? Any examples on how to use both?

Comment: I think that you might be a pioneer in this somehow. I hadn't even heard of behat. it sounds and looks useful from the site.

Comment: What elements of your application are you looking to test? Full stack, UI, API's? There are a number of different approaches depending on your testing aims.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got it working.  It works with `PHPUnit` and `Zend_Test` so you can use all those nifty `assertXYZ()` methods.  First, make sure you've got `behat` installed and available in your system `$PATH`.  I did the following:

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com
sudo pear channel-discover pear.behat.org
sudo pear install behat/behat
```

Now, create a directory structure like so:

```
features
    application
        ControllerTestCase.php
    bootstrap
        FeatureContext.php
    homepage.feature
```

The `features/application/ControllerTestCase.php` class is typical of a `Zend_Test` testing implementation:

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
require_once 'Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php';

class ControllerTestCase extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase {

    public $application;

    public function setUp() {
        $this->application = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH 
                . '/configs/application.ini');
        $this->bootstrap = array($this, 'appBootstrap');
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function appBootstrap(){
        $this->application->bootstrap();
    }
}
```

The `features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php` class is what Behat needs to bootstrap itself:

```
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Context\ClosuredContextInterface,
    Behat\Behat\Context\TranslatedContextInterface,
    Behat\Behat\Context\BehatContext,
    Behat\Behat\Exception\PendingException;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode,
    Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;

require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework/Assert/Functions.php';

define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'testing');
define('APPLICATION_PATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/../path/to/your/zf/application');

set_include_path('.' . PATH_SEPARATOR . APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'
        . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application/ControllerTestCase.php';

class FeatureContext extends BehatContext {

    protected $app;

    /**
     * Initializes context.
     * Every scenario gets it's own context object.
     *
     * @param array $parameters context parameters (set up via behat.yml)
     */
    public function __construct(array $parameters) {
        $this->app = new ControllerTestCase();
        $this->app->setUp();
    }

    /**
     * @When /^I load the URL "([^"]*)"$/
     */
    public function iLoadTheURL($url) {
        $this->app->dispatch($url);
    }

    /**
     * @Then /^the module should be "([^"]*)"$/
     */
    public function theModuleShouldBe($desiredModule) {
        $this->app->assertModule($desiredModule);
    }

    /**
     * @Given /^the controller should be "([^"]*)"$/
     */
    public function theControllerShouldBe($desiredController) {
        $this->app->assertController($desiredController);
    }

    /**
     * @Given /^the action should be "([^"]*)"$/
     */
    public function theActionShouldBe($desiredAction) {
        $this->app->assertAction($desiredAction);
    }

    /**
     * @Given /^the page should contain a "([^"]*)" tag that contains "([^"]*)"$/
     */
    public function thePageShouldContainATagThatContains($tag, $content) {
        $this->app->assertQueryContentContains($tag, $content);
    }

    /**
     * @Given /^the action should not redirect$/
     */
    public function theActionShouldNotRedirect() {
        $this->app->assertNotRedirect();
    }

}
```

And now you can write features like `features/homepage.feature`:

```
Feature: Homepage
  In order to know ZF works with Behat
  I need to see that the page loads.

Scenario: Check the homepage
  Given I load the URL "/index"
  Then the module should be "default"
  And the controller should be "index"
  And the action should be "index"
  And the action should not redirect
  And the page should contain a "title" tag that contains "My Nifty ZF App"
```

To run the tests, `cd` to the directory that contains the `features` folder, and type `behat`.

Good luck!

Comment: Is there a way to have step definitions in separate files? Not all of them in one `FeatureContext` class?

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me. the ZF bootstrap must be getting called multiple times, because I'm getting "Constant already defined" errors

Answer (score 0):

Codeception [has module for Zend Framework](http://codeception.com/01-27-2012/bdd-with-zend-framework.html). It's much like Behat, but tests are written in PHP DSL and not in Gherkin.

Answer (score 0):

My scenario was always stopping at the first step. I finally figured it out, there was a die or and exit somewhere in my code which was halting behat completety. So make sure your app doesn't contain any die or exit. Now it's working fine.