# How to bootstrap a Zend Framework 2 application for testing with Behat

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, behat

I'm using ZF `2.5.0` on a legacy application that we are going to write tests for.

I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667444/zend-framework-integration-with-behat-bdd) as a reference, but mainly changed many things regarding autoloading.

I'm basically manually instantiating a subclass of `AbstractControllerTestCase` inside my `FeatureContext`. I'm specifically trying to get a `ServiceLocator` instance, so I can load my dependencies (for instance: `$locator->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');`).

In order to understand how to bootstrap it, I read the [tutorial for `PHPUnit`](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/tutorials/unittesting.html#bootstrapping-your-tests). While reading this tutorial, I noticed the `Boostrap` class creates an instance of a `ServiceManager` on it's `init()` class method, but I fail to see how this instance is injected into the application instance that is created by `AbstractControllerTestCase`.

Any explanation or clarification on this would be appreciated. Or in general about how do I bootstrap an application to work with Behat.

Answer (score 1):

I created extension for integration ZF2/3 with Behat. https://github.com/alteris/behat-zendframework-extension

Maybe this help you.

Comment: Quick question, does this extension bootstrap the zf application, or do I still need a webserver up?

Comment: Bootstrap Zf application, but not webserver. You can directly call serviceManager etc. but if you want call front-end, need webserver.